# Conservation of angular momentum in electric quadrupole transition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, spectroscopy, multipole-expansion

I know that We can classify radiative transitions of electrons between different energy levels as electric multipole transitions or magnetic multipole transitions.

My question is:
In electric quadrupole transition total spin quantum number of electron changes by 2 units. Photon can carry only one unit of angular momentum. Where does the extra one unit of angular momentum goes? Does the extra unit of angular momentum is carried away by the nucleus of the atom. Or photon can have orbital angular momentum and the extra unit of angular momentum is carried away by the photon as its orbital angular momentum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emitted photon can have orbital angular momentum as well as its intrinsic spin angular momentum (which is always $\pm \hbar$).

Comment: Can you please confirm these statements: (1.)           In electric multipole transitions, the electron changes its orbital angular momentum, leading to transitions between different electron shells or orbitals within the same shell.

(2.)   In magnetic multipole transitions, the electron changes its spin angular momentum, resulting in transition